# Why don't I see the Firebase Web App API key?

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

Another app to add click > web click > Add a web app Firebase.

My situation

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.4.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
     // Initialize Firebase
     var config = {
       apiKey: "",
       authDomain: "********.firebaseapp.com",
       databaseURL: "https://**********.firebaseio.com",
       storageBucket: "********.appspot.com",
       messagingSenderId: "*********"
     };
     firebase.initializeApp(config);
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Firebase Console](http://console.firebase.google.com). Select your app then you have your separated platform (ios, android) if ever you created two platforms already, if not, Click the additional settings from the upper right of the app, then click Manage. see image below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I ios, android is the use of both. However, Tell me a little bit more about the answer Screenshots

Comment: are you using going to use FCM?

Comment: the screenshot will give you your web api key, under "Manage"

Comment: please mark as answer if it solved your problem. thanks